# Retrieve a ListViewItem's value

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView populated with the code below. Ask you can see, I set both the DisplayMember and the ValueMember. What I am wanting to do is find a ListViewItem by its ValueMember. So essentially what I'm looking for is ListViewItem.Value. I know I can get SelectedValue for the ListView itself, but I just don't see any properties on the ListViewItem that give me what I'm looking for. Am I just missing something, or is there no way to do this?

```
private void PopulateList(Globals.DataFieldMappingTypes mappingType)
    {
        ListBox lst = GetListBox(mappingType);
        ComboBox cbo = cboh.GetComboBox(new ComboBoxHandler.CboInfo(Globals.NodeTypes.DataField, mappingType));
        string sql = "select DataFieldReferenceValueId, [Value] from DataFieldReferenceValueInfo where DataFieldId = " + cbo.SelectedValue.ToString();
        DataTable tbl = dal.GetTable(sql, "DataFieldReferenceValue");
        lst.DisplayMember = "Value";
        lst.ValueMember = "DataFieldReferenceValueId";
        lst.DataSource = tbl.DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: Use the selected item to retrieve the object from the underlying bound collection

Comment: But the item won't be selected. I'm looping through all items to find one by DataFieldReferenceId.

Comment: then I would suggest to loop through the underlying bound collection. Why bothering with the `ListBox`. This is what binding is good for. For easy display of data. If you want to handle the data, get to the source. :)

Comment: What I want to do is color the ListViewItem. Looping through the underlying data does me no good unless I can match a value to an item.

Comment: "I have a ListView" but in your code I see `ListBox lst = GetListBox(mappingType);`. These are two different things. What is it now? the code or the question?

Comment: chaging the color in a listview is much easier ;)

Comment: @MongZhu yeah, I noticed that mistake and fixed it. Anyway, I ended up solving this problem a different way. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are not getting the values from DataTable correctly I guess. 
I hope tbl.Rows[0][0].ToString() will have the DataFieldReferenceValueId and
tbl.Rows[0][1].ToString() will have the [Value]

Please check the below MSDN link
https://forums.asp.net/t/1188002.aspx?how+to+read+DataTable+Rows+value+and+put+it+into+the+string+

Comment: I don't think that does what I want. I don't know which row in the DataTable the ListViewItem corresponds to, because I can't get the value. I guess I could do it by text, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading your dataTable straight in as the dataSource why don't you create a class to define the values?

```
    public class SqlTable
    {
            public string Name {get;set;}
            public string Value {get;set;}
    }

    var listPair = new List<SqlTable>();
```

Then load the list with your SqlDataReader and grab your desired pair with LINQ.

```
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
            listPair.Add(new SqlTable() { Name = sdr[0].ToString(), Value = sdr[1].ToString() });
    }
    lst.DisplayMember = "Name";
    lst.ValueMember = "Value";
    lst.DataSoure = listPair;

    SqlTable sqlTable = listPair.Find(x => x.Name == "Whatever name you are searching for") as SqlTable;
```

The SqlTable item is now the one you are searching for and you can get its properties by going:

```
    string value = sqlTable.Value;
    string name = sqlTable.Name;
```

**Edit from comment begins here:**

Well your first issue is that the 'lst' item in your example is a ListBox and not a ListView. It you switch it to a listview you can still feed your List of listPair items like so:

```
    ListView lst = new ListView();
    lst.View = View.Details;
    foreach (var data in listPair)
    {
            lst.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(listPair.Name, listPair.Value);
    }
```

So now you have a ListView that is a collection of your listPairs where each listPair is a ListViewItem. I assume you want to isolate the ListViewItem based on your value (or listPair.Value or sdr[1] or [Value] they are all the same now) in order to color it. You can now grab the listPair item like so:

```
    SqlTable pair = listPair.Find(x => x.Value == "Whatever the Value value is that you want to color");
    ListViewItem searchedItem = lst.FindItemWithText(pair.Name);
    searchedItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red; //or whatever color you choose
```

You can now use searchedItem to grab its index in the ListView and all its other properties. The ListPair just allows you to associate the values.

Comment: I still have to be able to match the value to an item, because what I want to do is color the item once it's found. How do I get from ListViewItem to SqlTable?

Comment: OK, I think that would work. I ended up going a different route to solve this problem anyway, but I appreciate your time on this.